# Compounds in works of fiction

Tags: compounds, neologisms

I'm a non-native speaker. Recently, I read *Child Of God*  by  Cormac McCarthy.

McCarthy seems to have a habit of making up "new words" when it suits him.

E.g.

> The pipe crashed into the room in a cloud of **coalsoot**

Coalsoot struck me as an amalgamation of two words that I couldn't find in any dictionary online.

Now I wonder when it is suitable to employ such compounds.

For example, would it be okay to write *flintshard*, even though a dictionary doesn't list this term?

Comment: There is a fairly common phenomenon in English usage in which, over time, a two-word (usually two) term is replaced by a single compound word, and sometimes later by more compact form.  There are dozens of such compound words in common use in English.  I strongly advise you, however, to stick with established usage in your own writing.

Comment: McCarthy has his own writing style. If I recall correctly  he doesn't usually use quotation marks. There is nothing 'wrong' with *coalsoot*. It is clear from context what it means. As for *flintshard*, out of context I don't know if you mean *flint shard* or *flints hard*. McCarthy is just closing the space in *coal soot*, although most authors don't.

Comment: Your sentence *Coalsoot struck me as an amalgamation of two words that I couldn't find in any dictionary online* can easily be read as  you couldn't find the two words *coal* and  *soot* in a dictionary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a great question for writers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally not considered appropriate to coin new words when writing formal nonfiction, as in journalism, science and business writing, etc., unless there is no existing word that suffices. In that case, the word is often defined on the spot, or otherwise acknowledged as a neologism ("in a process we call 'XXX,'" for example). But McCarthy is a novelist. In creative writing, new words, which Shakespeare was famous for, fall under the heading of poetic license. In this case, the meaning of "coalsoot" seems perfectly clear, so much so that many would not bother to look it up. Other words that may seem more obscure may provide food for thought. You can bet that a writer of McCarthy's stature carefully regards every word he writes--everything is intentional, purposeful, meaningful.

In short, if a new word serves a purpose that no existing word can, it "would be okay" to use it, most especially in a creative context.